# How is "mvn clean install" different from "mvn install"?

Tags: java, build, maven, maven-3

What is the difference between `mvn clean install` and `mvn install`?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

`clean` is its own build lifecycle phase (which can be thought of as an action or task) in Maven. `mvn clean install` tells Maven to do the `clean` phase in each module before running the `install` phase for each module.

What this does is clear any compiled files you have, making sure that you're really compiling each module from scratch.

Comment: I always thought install including clean as one of its phase... until i see this

Comment: @shanyangqu Sadly, no.  `clean` is in a [separate lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), so it's not called by default.

Comment: 1. Re "_can be thought of as an action or task_": Maven phases are not _actions_ or _tasks_. If there's no plugin goal bound to a phase, neither an action nor a task, i.e. _nothing_ is done. A phase is more [a step or stage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774). 2. Re "_do the `clean` phase_": With `mvn clean` it passes the `pre-clean` and the `clean` phase of the `clean` lifecycle and executes plugin goals bound to each phase. 3. Re "_clear any compiled files_": Not only those but everything that resides under `${project.build.directory}`: `<artifact>.jar`, resources, folders, etc.

Comment: @JunchenLiu There are actually four items named `clean`: `clean` lifecycle with its `clean` phase, `clean` [prefix](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) for the  `maven-clean-plugin` with its `clean` goal. See also the comment to [this answer to _Maven: Lifecycle vs. Phase vs. Plugin vs. Goal_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466540/1744774).

Answer (score 65):

Maven lets you specify either goals or lifecycle phases on the command line (or both).

`clean` and `install` are [two different phases of two different lifecycles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference), to which [different plugin goals are bound](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) (either per default or [explicitly in your pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins))

The `clean` phase, per convention, is meant to make a build reproducible, i.e. it cleans up anything that was created by previous builds. In most cases it does that by calling [`clean:clean`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html), which deletes the directory bound to `${project.build.directory}` (usually called "target")

Comment: "install" is not a lifecycle. It's a phase in the default lifecycle. Though there is "clean" lifecycle, AFAIK this parameter specifies the "clean" phase in the "clean" lifecycle, not the "clean" lifecycle itself.

Comment: @Puce true, I meant "Phase", not lifecycle

Comment: There are actually 4 items named `clean`: the lifecycle and one of its phases; the [plugin prefix](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) of the Maven Clean Plugin and one of its goals.

Comment: @GeroldBroser what comments? :-)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd :D A klan's Scherzerl, ha? ;-) OK, Monty Python... +1

Answer (score 45):

You can call more than one <strike>target</strike> goal with maven. `mvn clean install` calls `clean` first, then `install`. You have to clean manually, because clean is not a standard <strike>target</strike> goal and not executed automatically on every install.

`clean` removes the target folder - it deletes all class files, the java docs, the jars, reports and so on. If you don't `clean`, then maven will only "do what has to be done", like it won't compile classes when the corresponding source files haven't changed (in brief).

<sup>we call it *target* in ant and *goal* in maven</sup>

Comment: I think in this context clean and install are lifecycle phases, not goals.

Comment: I totally agree with @JL_SO

Comment: `clean` doesn't _remove_ the `target` folder. It _cleans_ it. It's also not necessarily the folder named `target`, but the one defined by `${project.build.directory}`.

Answer (score 32):

To stick with the Maven terms:

- "clean" is a phase of the clean
  lifecycle
- "install" is a phase of the
  default lifecycle

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference

Comment: There are actually four items named `clean`: `clean` lifecycle with its `clean` phase, `clean` [prefix](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) for the `maven-clean-plugin` with its `clean` goal. See also the comment to [this answer to _Maven: Lifecycle vs. Phase vs. Plugin vs. Goal_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466540/1744774).

Comment: True, but clean in `mvn clean install` refers to the phase.

Comment: Yes, it does. My comment was not meant to be criticism but additional information for all future readers and seekers here.

Answer (score 7):

Ditto for @Andreas_D, in addition if you say update Spring from 1 version to another in your project without doing a clean, you'll wind up with both in your artifact. Ran into this a lot when doing Flex development with Maven.