# Executing a specific Maven phase

Tags: maven, phase

Is there any way to execute a specific phase in a maven build.  For example, if I only want to run those plug-ins that execute in the pre-integration-phase, does Maven provide a means to do that?

```
e.g.
mvn pre-integration-phase
```

Comment: Can you give an example where you need that ? Which reason do you have?

Comment: I need this in a build pipeline where we'd like to split up the phases into distinct steps in the build pipeline to better see where errors occur.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't call the life-cycle-phase itself but you can call the goals of the plugins which are bound to the life-cycle-phases.

```
mvn compile:testCompile

mvn failsafe:integration-test
```

but usually this shouldn't be needed...

Comment: But when you do `mvn clean install` you are calling the life-cycle-phases directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018701/how-is-mvn-clean-install-different-from-mvn-install

Comment: The problem with using `install` is that all phase before are also executed. And the questions was targeting to call just `install` without the previous life cycle phases which is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

No. You'd have to run the plugins manually.