# When Maven executes phase or goal or lifecycle?

Tags: maven, phase

When I was reading about Maven goals, phases on Stack Overflow, I came across two links in which one says:

> **when you execute maven you can specify a goal or a phase.**
>
> – [What is the difference/relation between maven goals and phases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205778/what-is-the-difference-relation-between-maven-goals-and-phases)

and the other says:

> **You can't call the life-cycle-phase itself but you can call the goals of the plugins which are bound to the life-cycle-phases.**
>
> – [Executing a specific Maven phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608176/executing-a-specific-maven-phase)

Which one is right? Or am I not understanding it?

Also can some give me simple examples Maven executing lifecycle/phase/goal.
And also Maven knows that it has to run phase or a goal? E.g. when I say `mvn install`, is it `install` phase or goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bombya Bo,

Think of Maven build life cycle like a fancy meal which has sequential phases:

- starter (resources)
- main (compile)
- dessert (package)
- coffee (install)
- digestif (deploy)

A goal is the actual food being served during that phase.

- starter: gazpacho
- main: steak; gravy; fries
- dessert: tiramisu
- coffee: cappuccino

In this analogy:

- pom.xml file is the equivalent of today's menu written on the chalk board
- calling `mvn` on the command line is the equivalent of placing your order to the waiter
- you can have more than one item of food/goal bound to a single phase (steak+gravy+fries)

If you like the house defaults, then you can just order the first N courses off the fixed menu:

```
"I'll take the 2 course meal"
$ mvn compile
```

You'll get everything up to and including the main course (ie gazpacho followed by steak+gravy+fries).

Calling a single goal is the equivalent of ordering a la carte:

```
"I'll take a Cobb salad plus the 2 course meal"
$ mvn javadoc:javadoc compile
```

If you want that goal to become a permanent addition to the menu, then add it to the pom file. That brings us back to calling:

```
$ mvn compile
```

which results in gazpacho+Cobb, followed by steak+gravy+fries.

A last point about binding a goal to a phase.

By default, each goal will run during a certain phase (Cobb salad usually served as a starter).
But you can override the phase binding, which is like telling the waiter `"I'll have a Cobb salad, but bring it at the same time as the main"`

Hope this clarifies the intuition behind goals vs. phases.

Comment: nice example ! pls confirm when you execute maven a goal ie mvn [goal] is that all phases before that goal will be executed ? like if i execute mvn deploy:depoly  then all the phases before that goal like compile , test will be executed ? or just deploy ?

Comment: Calling mvn goal like deploy:deploy goal will only perform that single action ("i just want a cappuccino"). Caling mvn phase like deploy tells maven to perform all goals leading up to and including it ("I'll take 3 course meal")

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke a single plugin, you need to invoke a goal of that plugin. Like

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

in this case you are invoking the goal tree of the dependency plugin

On the other hand, you can invoke a phase of maven by simply doing

```
mvn test
```

In this case you are invoking not a plugin but a phase. Note that plugin goals can be bound to specific phases as well. The difference is whether you invoke the full phase (and all the preceding phases implicitly) or just a single goal of a single plugin

[Here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Eclipse-and-Maven2/images/lifecycle.png) you can find all the phases of the default lifecycle (which can be modified, but i don't think you need to know about that for now), so as you can see, `install` is a phase