# How does maven perform the action?

Tags: java, maven

I have been using maven for sometime, and I understand some of the basics of maven. I want to know how actually it works, and in this quest, I have this question.

When we execute a command like this:

`mvn clean install`

From where does it get the instructions; comparing it with ant, in ant we have build.xml which instructs how to do the work.

Is there any "built-in" file which `mvn` uses to "see" what actions it has to do?

Any response to clarify this greatly appreciated.

Comment: How have you used Maven so far without the command `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I am not saying that I used maven without mvn clean install. Trying to understand how it works internally.

Comment: May be the following link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018701/how-is-mvn-clean-install-different-from-mvn-install
cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven is organized in [Build Lifecycles and phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). 
There are only 3 Lifecycles, namely

- clean
- build
- site

With build being the most relevant one , separated into several phases.
When you run `mvn install` you run the `install` phase of the build lifecycle.

Plugins and their goals are bound to phases. Maven delivers some [default plugins (like jar or war) that are bound](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) to the according phases.

But you can also explicitly bind (your own or other non standard) plugins to phases with the [`<execution>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag)tag. With this tag you bind one or more goals of a plugin to a phase of the build lifecycle (see link above).