# war already exists issue with maven and Team Foundation Server

Tags: maven, tomcat, tfs, war

I am using Maven build tool and Team Foundation Server in my J2EE project.
while I am doing the maven clean for the project, build success But when I am doing the maven install for the same project build is a success but in eclipse console, I am getting an error like

> **The item $/ProjConnect/Main/source/ProjWeb/target/test.war already
>   exists**

I am new to maven and Team Foundation Server.

**Is this error regarding maven or Team Foundation Server?**
and Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you run the build through TFS such as using [Maven task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/maven)? Or you just use TFS as a source control tool to store your code？

Answer (score 0):

> The `clean` phase, per convention, is meant to make a build
>   reproducible, i.e. it **cleans up anything that was created by
>   previous builds.** In most cases it does that by calling
>   [`clean:clean`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html), which deletes the directory bound to
>   `${project.build.directory}` (usually called "target")

According to the error, the `$/ProjConnect/Main/source/ProjWeb/target/test.war` should generated by a previous build. Without clean option the file will not deleted during the build pipeline. More details please take a look at this question: [How is "mvn clean install" different from "mvn install"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018701/how-is-mvn-clean-install-different-from-mvn-install)

Comment: Hi, Patrick-MSFT Thanks for your response.
But I am using the first maven clean and then only I am going to maven install.