# 'mvn clean' vs.'mvn clean install' (when a plugin execution is attached to 'clean')

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I want to install project-local dependencies (jar files) to my local maven repository (~/.m2) prior to compiling the project so I can reference them in my POM just like I would reference any dependency from Maven Central. Currently, I'm using Maven install plugin's install-file goal attached to the 'clean' phase (because my IDE uses it), like so:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact.id</artifactId>
      <version>artifact.version</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.2</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>install-my-local-dependency</id>
               <phase>clean</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>install-file</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <groupId>group.id</groupId>
                  <artifactId>artifact.id</artifactId>
                  <version>artifact.version</version>
                  <file>${project.basedir}/lib/local-dep.jar</file>
                  <packaging>jar</packaging>
                  <generatePom>true</generatePom>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

When I execute `mvn clean` (or its equivalent in the IDE), everything runs as I'd expect:

> --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ MyProject ---
>
> --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (install-...) @ MyProject ---
>   Installing ${project.basedir}/lib/local-dep.jar to ~/.m2/repository/group.id/artifact.id/local-dep.jar

But when I execute `mvn clean install` instead (or its equivalent in the IDE), I get the following error:

> Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.MyProject:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact group.id:artifact.id:jar:artifact.version in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

For some reason, Maven install plugin's install-file goal either does not run in this case, or doesn't run soon enough. Why? The other StackOverflow answers I found explain differences between both commands but in my eyes, they do not explain this particular difference as my project has no modules.

Is there a better way of doing the same thing cross-platform, even on build servers (e.g. Jenkins) and with at least one other dependent project?

Should it be any help, I have the following Maven versions:

- CLI: 3.6.0
- IDE: 3.3.9

Comment: How can you install the artifact without compiling it ?
If your dependency is coded as per your question then it will never work, as no such artifact exists anywhere. Your local repo is supposed to contain built artifacts

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018701/how-is-mvn-clean-install-different-from-mvn-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven first analyses the `pom.xml` and then calls the goals/phases. The analysis itself is complicated and has different depths, so I guess that calling `clean` alone will not make Maven analyse the dependencies, but calling `clean install` does so. Note that the analysis of the POM only happens once, not again for every goal/phase.

Generally, your approach cannot be recommended. Usually, you put project dependencies into remote Maven repositories, so that they can be resolved through them. If you work inside a company, you should set up a Nexus/Artifactory server that handles your artifacts.

If you want people outside your company to build the artifact, you need to find a provider for Maven repositories. I guess that github/gitlab can help you here. Then you need to add those repositories to the POM.