# Gatling with GitLab CI/CD

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gatling

I'm working on a project on gitlab, I'm trying to leverage maven's gatling plugin to run simulations.

I've added gatling's dependencies to the project, and the corresponding plugin, but I'm currently encountering this error whenever I run `mvn gatling:test`
via gitlab's pipeline's and even locally on the project

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.4:test (default-cli) on project myproject: Gatling failed.: Couldn't locate org.s
cala-lang:scala-library in classpath -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have some doubts about whether the dependencies are met, so I tried `mvn dependency:get`

YAML:

```
script:
  - echo "Hello World!"
  - uname -a
  - pwd
  #- mvn dependency:get -e -Dartifact=io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.4
  #- mvn dependency:get -e -Dartifact=io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:2.2.5
  - mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install -e
  - mvn gatling:test -e
```

Stack trace:

```
Gatling failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Gatling failed.
    at io.gatling.mojo.GatlingMojo.execute (GatlingMojo.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Couldn't locate org.scala-lang:scala-library in classpath
    at io.gatling.mojo.AbstractGatlingMojo.getVersion (AbstractGatlingMojo.java:109)
    at io.gatling.mojo.AbstractGatlingMojo.buildTestClasspath (AbstractGatlingMojo.java:92)
    at io.gatling.mojo.GatlingMojo.execute (GatlingMojo.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Edit:
I created an extra module for my project and added only gatling dependencies to it.

```
mvn gatling:test is now working and returns `No Simulations to run`
```

I haven't added simulations yet to the project.
This means the issue is related to the parent pom, as there are many dependencies and other tags I don't even recognize.

Comment: @IqbalAISAOUI did you make any progress?

Comment: Hi @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz, I tried to run gatling:test from the parent pom, added scala dependency to the plugin only, but I still get the same stack trace.

Meanwhile, the plugin runs on a new maven module for the same project

Comment: Also the module runs without the need to declare the scala dependency

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I've also ran the parent project with the dependency declared under <dependencyManagement>I build the project and then execute gatling:test which leads to the same error

Comment: I can see the scala jar 2.11.8 downloaded in the logs by maven 
[INFO] Downloaded from releases: ***/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/scala-library-2.11.8.jar (5.7 MB at 4.1 MB/s)

Comment: Did you added the dependency as a plugin dependency one??? (Inside the plugin)

Comment: yes, as stated in second comment, then I tried outside plugin.

Comment: ummmmm..... try to delete mavens local repository, and do a `clean install` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018701/how-is-mvn-clean-install-different-from-mvn-install

Comment: I'm running it on a gitlab runner after deleting m2 cached maven repo after a clean install

Comment: ummmm ... may you post your basic pom.xml structure to copy it and try to reproduce the issue??

Answer (score 1):

If you check under [gatlin-charts docs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.gatling.highcharts/gatling-charts-highcharts/2.2.5) -*that is the library you are using with `gatling-plugin`*-, scroll down, last section, and see the dependencies:

[image]

As you will see, in your log you have a `gatlin-plugin` message that says:

> Gatling failed.: Couldn't locate org.s cala-lang:scala-library in
>   classpath

So, you need to add the Scala dependencies to the parent `pom.xml` where you declared the plugin.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
```

If you click on the version number on that page, you will go to your required `scala-charts` version:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8

[image: maven repository scala library]

> NOTE: remember you can [add dependencies specifically](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag) for your
>   plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```